# How to change operators dynamically in rule file

Tags: java, drools

I want to evaluate facts dynamically using drool engine. Rule conditions attributes & their conditional operators are stored in database and load in to WM when engine start. 
So I want to use that operator in rule file as below.

```
$dynCx  : DynCustomer()
$attrib : Attribute() from $dynCx.attributes   
$offer  : Offer($ofCode : offer_code, $domainName : domainName ) 
$rdef   : OfferRuleDef($entity : entity,
         $code : code,
         $value : value,
         $atrName : attributeName,
         $atrVal : attributeVal,
         $op : operation,
         $entity == $domainName,
         $code == "OFFER_CODE",
         $value == $ofCode,
         $atrName == $attrib.name,          
         $atrVal $op $attrib.value                           
         )
```

but I'm getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: [59,14]: [ERR 102] Line 59:14 mismatched input '$op' in rule "Evaluate Generic Offer Eligibility"
[0,0]: Parser returned a null Package
```

How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Operators can't be resolved at runtime, so you can't write that kind of rule. Based on the version you are using and the number of operators you envision, you have a few options.

1) Write a rule for each operator:

```
OfferRuleDef( ..., operator == "==", attributeVal == $attrib.value )
```

to avoid excessive code repetition, consider that rules can "extend" each other.

2) In recent versions, create a static helper function and pass the three values:

```
OfferRuleDef( ..., MyHelper.applyOperator($attrValue, $op, $attrib.value) )
```

Comment: I used below. hope it is ok. Anyway i think your suggession is better than this.  
OfferRuleDef(  $entity : entity,  
    $code : code,  
    $value : value,  
    $atrName : attributeName,  
    $atrVal : attributeVal,  
    $op : operation,  
    $entity == $domainName,  
    $code == "OFFER_CODE",  
    $value == $ofCode,  
    $atrName == $attrib.name,  
    ($op == "=" && $atrVal == $attrib.value) ||  
    ($op == ">" && $attrib.value > $atrVal ) ||  
    ($op == "<" && $attrib.value < $atrVal)                
   )

Comment: @Davide When will Drools support lambdas? ;-)

Comment: Worth mentioning that it could also be done via rule templates/DSL?

Comment: @laune: ask Mario about LambdaConstraints, there is some work in progress, but also some inherent limitations